# How to get info about disk filesystem?

Tags: c#, filesystems, .net

Is possible to read info about the filesystem of a physical disk (e.g., if it is formatted as NTFS, FAT, etc.) using .NET C# 3.5?

If so, which class should I use to determine this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Query the [`DriveFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.driveformat.aspx) of the [`System.IO.DriveInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abt1306t.aspx).

```
public static void Main()
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sepehr Yes, thanks. I don't know what happened to the code sample. I didn't mean to have a bunch of random spaces, nor did I mean "File type".

Answer (score 2):

I think you also may be interesting in [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetVolumeInformation.html) function.

**[EDIT]**
You also can use WMI objects for obtaining such information, for example:

```
using System.Management;
.....
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
disk.Get();
MessageBox.Show(disk["FreeSpace"] + " bytes");  // Displays disk free space
MessageBox.Show(disk["VolumeName"].ToString()); // Displays disk label
MessageBox.Show(disk["FileSystem"].ToString()); // Displays File system type
```

For list of all avaliable properties of `Win32_LogicalDisk` class see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The `DriveInfo` function is a managed wrapper around this very function. That means there's really little reason to P/Invoke and call the function yourself.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes, you are right, but OP may want to read disk serial number, as far as I know this is not possible with DriveInfo